# How can you request a photo from the photo stream to be downloaded with the Assets Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, photostream

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAsset/defaultRepresentation) states:

```
- (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation
```

> This method returns nil for assets from a shared photo stream that are not yet available locally. If the asset becomes available in the future, an ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification notification is posted.

How can you request a download for a shared photo? I first thought a user had to go to the photo's app to achieve it, but in the Telegram.app they were able to achieve it so it is possible for a third party app. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Same question (no perfect solution though) here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079776/how-to-get-a-alassetrepresentation-of-a-shared-photostream-alasset

Comment: Thank you, I will close this question and contribute to that issue. To keep it clean. Funny, they also found app that accomplished it. So it is possible interesting.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any solution yet. Good luck !

Comment: I found the answer =)